# Magento 1.6.1 - Delete from cart redirects to homepage (with Varnish running)

Tags: magento, e-commerce, varnish

I've got a really weird issue on Magento 1.6.1.

We have 3 platforms, DEV, TST, LIVE (current active running website).

We're running Varnish in front of the live site too.

The problem is that on the LIVE site when you remove something (using the delete button) from the cart you always get redirected to the homepage. If you remove items by setting their quantity to 0 then its fine.

This issue doesn't occur on the same codebase on DEV or TST.

Could this be Varnish interfering somehow? Any suggestions?

Comment: I've just had this issue in a website because of the MW_Ajaxcart extension: do you have this extension installed?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running Varnish on the dev/staging sites? It doesn't sound like you are.

I'm guessing that your Varnish module for Magento has an observer to detect if the cart has any contents (ie. to see if you actually have a session unique to you), but when you empty your cart, this observer then fires the nocache header to Varnish and Varnish is returning a new (cached, non-cookie) response and bouncing you back to the homepage.

It sounds like your Varnish module is the reason.

Remove Varnish and its associated Magento module, then re-test. Seems like a fairly easy way to rule it out.

Comment: Thats the conclusion we've come to. It looks like it may be to do with the port Varnish runs the web server on and the internal URL check in Magento's router thinking that a port 8080 address isn't local.

Comment: That's the problem. Running Nginx/Apache on port 80 will pass the redirect URL as internal. Then passing incoming traffic to Varnish using iptables. http://erikeng.se/post/magento-behind-varnish.html

Answer (score 0):

The one thing which struck me when configuring my local environment to use Varnish in front of Nginx was that application redirects started acting wierd. Adding a product for comparision from a product view redirected me to the base URL, instead of back to the product view (referer). So I started digging into the core to see what actually going on.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:773
```

The `_getRefererUrl` method looks for any referer URL in the request URI or from request headers. For some reason the `$refererUrl` did not pass as `_isUrlInternal` which makes it fall back to the base URL.

```
/**
 * Identify referer url via all accepted methods (HTTP_REFERER, regular or base64-encoded request param)
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getRefererUrl()
{
    $refererUrl = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_REFERER_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = $url;
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
    }
    if ($url = $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($url);
    }

    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($refererUrl);

    if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($refererUrl)) {
        $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }
    return $refererUrl;
}
```

---

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:799
```

Here Magento’s looking for the position of the (base URL) string http://domain.com/ in (the referer URL) http://domain.com:8080/any/url.html, which will never be found because of the port number Nginx was listening on (behind Varnish).

```
/**
 * Check url to be used as internal
 *
 * @param   string $url
 * @return  bool
 */
protected function _isUrlInternal($url)
{
    if (strpos($url, 'http') !== false) {
        /**
         * Url must start from base secure or base unsecure url
         */
        if ((strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl()) === 0)
            || (strpos($url, Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK, true)) === 0)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php:37
```

That port number is (for some odd reason) added when building the current URL in Magento.

```
/**
 * Retrieve current url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentUrl()
{
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $port = $request->getServer('SERVER_PORT');
    if ($port) {
        $defaultPorts = array(
            Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT,
            Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT
        );
        $port = (in_array($port, $defaultPorts)) ? '' : ':' . $port;
    }
    $url = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $port . $request->getServer('REQUEST_URI');
    return $url;
}
```

Getting the redirects working again

Without altering the application, your webserver (Nginx) needs to be listening on port 80 (or 443) while still keeping Varnish in front of it. This can be accomplished by using iptables.